# CSV reading in C#, I just want to read some fields

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I want to read a csv file that has 9 columns with **headers** and many data rows below, but I am just interested in three of the columns, and they are **not contiguous**. I have tried with this code but it doesn't work, it stops in the foreach loop with a runtime exception from CsvHelper "'Field with name 'Y' does not exist. You can ignore missing fields by setting MissingFieldFound to null.'".

The csv file is like this:

**FrameNO** ,   Ttotal,  TNo,  X,     **Y** ,   Z  ,  Speed ,  **Intensity**,    ILog  ;
   1 ,         9 ,     1 , 0.08,  1.4  , 0  ,     0   ,   78  ,         19 ,  ;;
   1 ,        9 ,     2  ,0.1  , 1.56 , 0 ,      0    ,  228 , 28, ;;

```
using CsvHelper;

namespace RadarPrototipo.Clases
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public int FrameNO { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public int Intensity { get; set; }
    }
    class CCalc
    {
        public double Calc(int f)
        {
            double d=1.5;
            int inten=0;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Uni/AlumnoInterno/grab.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {

                csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
                var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
                csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;

                foreach (var Foo in records)
                {
                    if (Foo.FrameNO == f)
                    {
                        if (Foo.Y < 1.8 && Foo.Y > 1.5)
                        {
                            if (Foo.Intensity > inten)
                            {
                                inten = Foo.Intensity;
                                d = Foo.Y;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return d;
        }
    }
}
```

The function analyses the data on those three columns and selects the best answer according to the conditions, then returns the value Y which is a distance.
Any help is really thanked.

Comment: What CSV-reading package are you using?

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932863/reading-only-specific-columns-from-a-csv-file-out-of-many

Comment: How does your csv look like? Are there column headers? Is the spelling/casing identical to yours in the Foo class?

Comment: Please verify that the code you've posted to us is the *actual* code, as the code in your question **should work** just fine. `Foo`, the variable in your `foreach` will contain a `FrameNO` property just fine. It would be better if you supplied us with a full piece of code that exhibits the problem, and not just a comment saying "the problem could be here if I wrote more code". Please post a full [mcve].

Comment: Also, can you please tell us if the problem is that the **compiler** gives you an error that `FrameNO` doesn't exist, or if you get a **runtime exception** from CsvHelper that the column `FrameNO` doesn't exist in the csv file. Does the csv file contain headers? If so, does it contain a column/field named FrameNO?

Comment: you have to put all csv file columns to the `Foo` class properties. `CsvReader` loads csv columns using the generic argument properties count I suppose. To read the csv file properly your `Foo` implementation should have all columns defined.

Comment: First of all, you have to map your 'Foo' class properties after retrieving the values from the CSV file. You can retrieve the values by splitting based on the separators of your csv file.

Comment: you have to use the `Index` attribute to set up Foo class properties if headers are not specified in the file. And set `csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false` and `csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null` like [it is documented](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/)

Comment: @oleksa No, that is not necessary. If the csv file contains headers that match the properties, you do not have to map properties to every column in the file, CsvHelper will skip the columns it doesn't have properties for.

Comment: Also be aware that if a problem with the mapping existed, the error message would be tied to the line with the foreach loop, due to delayed execution because the GetRecords method returns an IEnumerable, and not inside the loop body. I still want OP to post a better example that more concisely describes and shows the actual problem. I suspect we're all barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I just updated the question, so it's now more complete and may show the error. I added information relating many of the questions made in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("FrameNO,Column2,Y,Column4,Column5,Column6,Intensity,Column8,Column9");
            writer.WriteLine("1,two,1.123,four,five,six,10,eight,nine");
            writer.WriteLine("2,two,2.345,four,five,six,20,eight,nine");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
            foreach (var Foo in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Foo.FrameNO);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int FrameNO { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public int Intensity { get; set; }
}
```

One thing you might try is setting your delimiter.  Your cultural default might not be a comma. Also, if you have spaces between your data and the commas, you will need to set the `TrimOptions`.

```cs
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
    csv.Configuration.TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim;
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
```

Comment: it will work only if there are column names in the file. I've just tried the code you have shown but without column names. It raises the same error `Header with name 'FrameNO' was not found`.

Comment: You are correct, but the original poster advised that the csv file had headers. If it doesn't have headers with 'FrameNO', 'Y' and 'Intensity', then you would have to map them by column numbers.

Comment: When mapping isn't the cause for this type of exception, the next most likely issue is the delimiter.  CsvHelper defaults to the cultural delimiter of the user, which causes issues for those whose cultural delimiter is not a comma.  @oleska Try my code above but add `csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";`

Comment: I'm getting the `The conversion cannot be performed.    Text: '1,1,10,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine'` error with `Delimiter = ";"`. It does not look to be the same as the original one (unfortunately it is not clear what is the original error). CsvReader uses the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator` I do not know was it changed on the TS computer or not.

Comment: That's strange. It should have failed with the header row.  Did you include the header row? I'm getting `CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException: 'Header with name 'FrameNO' was not found.` And you are correct.  We need more information on the original poster's data and exact exception message.

Comment: I updated the information on the question so as to be more helpful.

Comment: Add `csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";` before `var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();`

Comment: It now recognizes FrameNO but shows the same problem for the next field "Y"

Comment: What exactly is the error message?  Also confirming you have commas separating the data. You show it separated by spaces in your question.

Comment: CsvHelper.MissingFieldException: 'Field with name 'Y' does not exist. You can ignore missing fields by setting MissingFieldFound to null.'

Comment: If your data has spaces between the data and the commas, you could add `csv.Configuration.TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim;` before `var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();`