# Read the first column of a csv file in c#?

Tags: c#, csv

Is there an easy way to just read and display the first column of a CSV file in c#?
Something like this?

```
String csv = File.ReadAllLines("@..\..\..\Data.csv).Split(',')[0];
Console.WriteLine(csv);
```

or do I have to loop over every line in the csv file and just take the first value for each line?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with looping it? If looping works, do it and keep moving. You can use LINQ but even that is going to use a loop under the hood. One suggestion, use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` but even this may not make a difference so it's just a suggestion.

Comment: What's the motive?   How large is the CSV?  Are you after something with fewer lines of code or something that doesn't use excessive computer resources?

Comment: Do not confuse one-liners with 'easy solutions' !

Comment: there is no way to skip reading all other "columns" in the CSV file and read only the first one. CSV is plain-text file and the line length may vary (no way to read first column and skip to the next line. I suppose that you should use existing framework (like CsvHelper as it was said already) and do not reinvent a wheel (if it is not a school homework)

Comment: Your solution will fail if there is a , inside of quotes in the first column. You need to skip quoted text to get to the separator character (which does not have to be a comma).

Answer (score 1):

For reading csv files, I recommend using [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper). You can use it like this:

```
var firstColumn = new List<string>();
using (var fileReader = File.OpenText("@..\..\..\Data.csv"))
using (var csvResult  = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(fileReader))
{
    while (csvResult.Read())
    {
        var field = csvResult.GetField<string>(0);
        firstColumn.Add(field);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46933266/10860445), you can choose which columns of your csv to extract.

```
var csv = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:..\..\..\Data.csv");
public List<MyMappedCSVFile>() myExtraction = new List<MyMappedCSVFile>();
foreach(string line in csv)
{
  var delimitedLine = line.Split(',');

  myExtraction.Add(new MyMappedCSVFile(delimitedLine[0], delimitedLine[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static async Task<HashSet<string>> GetFirstLineAsync(string fileFullname)
{
  try
  {
    var firstLine = await File.OpenText(fileFullname).ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return firstLine.Split(';').ToHashSet();
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
  {
   // TODO: Handle the System.UnauthorizedAccessException
  }
  catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
  {
   // TODO: Handle the System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
  {
   // TODO: Handle the System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  }
  catch (ArgumentException ex)
  {
   // TODO: Handle the System.ArgumentException
  }
  catch (PathTooLongException ex)
  {
   // TODO: Handle the System.IO.PathTooLongException
  }
  catch (NotSupportedException ex)
  {
   // TODO: Handle the System.NotSupportedException
  }
  catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
  {
   // TODO: Handle the System.ObjectDisposedException
  }
  catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
  {
    // TODO: Handle the System.InvalidOperationException
  }
  return null;
}
```

And Call it like this:

```
var firstLine = await GetFirstLineAsync(@"C:\Temp\Test.csv").ConfigureAwait(false);
```